# How can I migrate my Atom Zombie Smasher saves to a Mac?

Tags: atom-zombie-smasher

Atom zombie smasher is a great deal of fun, but it seems that other than smashing zombies it is also a good game for smashing my computer, as I get BSODs much too often while playing it.

The issue I am facing is a known one, and I tried the official solution as described [in the game's official forum](http://www.blendogames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=798).

Sadly, when I tried to see if that actually alleviates my BSOD issues, the game would no longer recognize the profile I was playing with. It's still there, but the game won't load it (it gives some unhelpful error message when I try that).

Since I was doing really well with that campaign, I'd hate to lose all my progress, so I thought I'd kill two zeds with one stone by moving my saves to my Mac, which should be immune to the BSOD issue, and still has the game's original executable, so I hope that it will load my save without making too much of a fuss.

So, how do I go about moving my saves from a Windows machine to a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save game paths are given in the [Atom Zombie Smasher FAQ](http://blendogames.com/atomzombiesmasher/help.htm).

Here's the procedure:

- On the Windows machine, navigate to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\AtomZombieData` (username being whatever your username is on Windows)
- In this directory, you'll see "profiles" and under "profiles" there will be one for your Atom Zombie Smasher profile name.  Open that folder.
- Copy all the .sav files you wish to migrate to some device or network share
- If you don't have a profile yet on the Mac, start the game up and create one.
- On the Mac, navigate to `~\Library\Application Support\AtomZombieData`
- Open the "profiles" folder, and then the profile you wish to copy the saves to
- Copy the .sav files from the device/network share to this folder

Once you've done this, you can load Atom Zombie Smasher on the Mac, and then hit the "File Manager" button on the right hand side.  You'll see all your save games and you can choose the one you want to load.

I tried this with a few of my own Windows save games on my Mac, and everything seemed to go smoothly.  Good luck!

Comment: I had a feeling I could count on you. I'll give it a go later today and mark your answer (as the answer).